# How to stop maven from downloading some jar files from repositorty

Tags: maven-3

I am modifying the hadoop source code but when I do a compile in maven it downloads from the maven repository, which is causing problems as my changes are not always be used.

How can I get maven to not download some files from the repository at all, and just use what is in the local classpath?

I am using maven 3.0.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to **give to "hadoop source code" a different SNAPSHOT version or a different artifactId** and refer to it.

However, I think it is a stupid answer.

- You can set local settings to `offline=true`. http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.3/maven-settings/settings.html;
- or use a repository manager (sucha as Nexus) http://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html and deploy to Repository

Comment: I will try offline=true and see if that works, otherwise I am probably going to see about creating a jar file when the hadoop-common project compiles and copy it to the repository.  Not the best option, so I hope your idea works, as I don't want to deploy it elsewhere right now.

Answer (score 1):

**Update these properties inside of your POM file to disable updates of your dependencies.**

- **enabled**: true or false for whether this repository is enabled for the
  respective type (releases or snapshots).
- **updatePolicy**: This element    specifies how often updates should
  attempt to occur. Maven will    compare the local POM's timestamp
  (stored in a repository's    maven-metadata file) to the remote. The
  choices are: always, daily    (default), interval:X (where X is an
  integer in minutes) or never.

[POM Reference - MAVEN Site](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repositories)